# Tap actions on Android wear watchfaces

Tags: wear-os, watch-face-api, watchmaker

So, I know this is undocumented and unsupported and not recommended etc.

But, I haven't given up on trying to add a button to an Android watchface. If you are familiar with WatchMaker, you know they support this feature!

My guess is that is has something to do with implementing `onCommand` on the engine, but I have encountered 2 problems with this method:

1. For some reason the X and Y are always 0 there
2. I don't know how to disable the default tap action that takes you to the menu.

Anyways, if someone can guess or know how WatchMaker are doing this, please suggest a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/btrax/on-task)

In fact, these WatchFaces add views in the `WindowManager` that have an `onClickListener` when visible.

Comment: They won't. A watchface should not be clickable to let other components of the stream behave as expected.